# Filter array on a predicate angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an `object array` that I want to filter the data by matching it to a predicate. The complexity lies in construction of the `predicate`, which in this case would resemble that of a `query` built using a `Map` datastructure.

Here is what my `array` of objects looks like:

```
var data = [
   {"id" : 1, "name": "bob", "address": "123 abc", "status": "active"},
   {"id" : 2, "name": "henry", "address": "123 def", "status": "inactive"},
   {"id" : 3, "name": "henry", "address": "123 hij", "status": "active"}
];
```

Here is the `Map` structure, from what the `predicate should be constructed:

```
var map = new Map<string, any>();
map.set("name", ["henry", "bob"]);
map.set("status", "active");
```

The correct output in this case should be:

```
[{"id" : 3, "name": "henry", "address": "123 hij", "status": "active"}]
```

Now, how should I write my `data.filter((item) => {...})` routine, so that it dynamically constructs the `predicate` and filters the results. I do not want to hardcode the `property` names, as they could be any one of the properties to filter on.

Secondly, the value is of `type any`, which means it could a `string`, `array` or a number. The predicate is evaluating to something similar to this:

```
data.filter((item) => 
{ item["name"] IS IN map.get("name").values[]
  && item["status"] IS EQUAL TO map.get("status").value)});
```

I cannot figure out how to flatten out the `Map` object into a predicate and then filter the necessary. Any cues or help would be really helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty rough and ready, but something like the below might get you on the right track (works for your simple dataset).

```
const predicate = item => {
  for (let [key, value] of map) {
    if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key)) return false;
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
        if (item[key] !== value) return false;
    }
    if (!value.includes(item[key])) return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: This looks very promising, though when trying to make it work, I cannot use `for of`, instead `foreach` is working. However, cant short circuit out of `foreach`..

Comment: Why not just use a regular `for` loop instead of `forEach`?

Comment: I am using `es5` and a `map` datatype, where all the `keys() and .entries()` work and return a map iterable, how do you suggest to iterate in a for loop?

Comment: I was thinking using `Array.from`, as I assumed your `Map` was ES6. There is probably a polyfill available, that will enable the above to work, just assign key and value in the loop.

Comment: FInally, I ended up using `foreach` and instead of `return`, I used `throw true/false` instead.. as it is impossible to return from `foreach`, catching the `exception` was the only way out..